# GitLab docker image does not reconfigure certain parameters from gitlab.rb after a change has been made

Tags: docker, gitlab

#### Environment

- Host System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Apache 2.24 on host w/ reverse proxy to the container

  ```
  $ sudo docker version
  Client:
   Version:      17.06.0-ce
   API version:  1.30
   Go version:   go1.8.3
   Git commit:   02c1d87
   Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:23:31 2017
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

  Server:
   Version:      17.06.0-ce
   API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
   Go version:   go1.8.3
   Git commit:   02c1d87
   Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:19:04 2017
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
   Experimental: false

  $ sudo docker info
  Containers: 1
   Running: 1
   Paused: 0
   Stopped: 0
  Images: 3
  Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
  Storage Driver: aufs
   Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
   Backing Filesystem: extfs
   Dirs: 30
   Dirperm1 Supported: true
  Logging Driver: json-file
  Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
  Plugins:
   Volume: local
   Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
   Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
  Swarm: inactive
  Runtimes: runc
  Default Runtime: runc
  Init Binary: docker-init
  containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
  runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
  init version: 949e6fa
  Security Options:
   apparmor
   seccomp
    Profile: default
  Kernel Version: 4.4.0-47-generic
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
  OSType: linux
  Architecture: x86_64
  CPUs: 4
  Total Memory: 15.67GiB
  Name: <masked>
  ID: CWMI:WONN:2RZP:5HFD:GN52:BO3S:GNNW:P6WJ:5MQJ:PQLG:ZTWR:4JHM
  Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
  Debug Mode (client): false
  Debug Mode (server): false
  Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
  Experimental: false
  Insecure Registries:
   127.0.0.0/8
  Live Restore Enabled: false
  ```

#### Issue

I have torn down and rebuilt this server so many times in the last week getting various other items to function in my particular setup. It seems like when I first built the server, it saved a lot of my configuration but now does not allow me to change it.

Here is the SMTP/Email portion of my `gitlab.rb` (with my actual fqdn replaced by "mydomain.com":

```
### Email Settings
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@mydomain.com'
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'GitLab'
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_subject_suffix'] = ''

### GitLab email server settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html
###! **Use smtp instead of sendmail/postfix.**

# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mysmtp"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
# gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "<username>"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "<pass>"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "mysmtp"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "plain"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true

###! **Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert'**
###! Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
# gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'

# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

Based on the information from GitLab's SMTP documentation, I should be able to test sending mail via the ruby console like this:

```
gitlab-rails console
irb(main):007:0> Notify.test_email('adam@adamwgay.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now
```

However, the output from the console is unexpected. None of my settings from `gitlab.rb` are present, and it seems to be using some default set of options (including attempting to use `sendmail`, which it spits up an error about right at the beginning).

```
irb(main):007:0> Notify.test_email('adam@adamwgay.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now

Notify#test_email: processed outbound mail in 1.2ms
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found

Sent mail to adam@adamwgay.com (5.8ms)
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2017 19:16:15 +0000
From: GitLab <gitlab@gitlab.mydomain.com>
Reply-To: GitLab <noreply@gitlab.mydomain.com>
To: adam@adamwgay.com
Message-ID: <597798ff6423a_9593fdebe2c710863b8@gitlab.mydomain.com>
Subject: Message Subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Message Body</p></body></html>

=> #<Mail::Message:70225704413280, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2017 19:16:15 +0000>, <From: GitLab <gitlab@gitlab.mydomain.com>>, <Reply-To: GitLab <noreply@gitlab.mydomain.com>>, <To: adam@adamwgay.com>, <Message-ID: <597798ff6423a_9593fdebe2c710863b8@gitlab.mydomain.com.mail>>, <Subject: Message Subject>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>, <Auto-Submitted: auto-generated>, <X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All>>
```

There are a couple of issues that I see with this output, and something tells me that the SMTP settings from gitlab.rb are not being parsed/delivered to the GitLab system properly:

- All the `From` and `Reply-To` fields in this output DO NOT match what I have set in `gitlab.rb`
- This line, `sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`, seems to indicate the system is still trying to use sendmail. Again, not what I have set in `gitlab.rb`

Looking further, It seems that nothing in my `gitlab.rb` file is being updated upon running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` then restarting the container.

- If I change settings directly (even if there's a volume on my host), say the nginx conf files, then a restart always reverts the settings, despite what I have set in the `gitlab.rb` file.
- If I add a file to try and force the SMTP settings on the container, then again a restart removes this file.

Is there another way to apply the settings from `gitlab.rb` to the container that I have missed?

My order of ops:

1. Make my changes in `gitlab.rb`
2. Run `sudo docker exec gitlab gitlab-ctl reconfigure` or just `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` inside the container
3. Run `sudo docker restart gitlab` or `gitlab-ctl restart` inside the container

Even though both ways give me a successful reconfigure message, the settings are not changed. At some point, changes I made to `gitlab.rb` got stored into the container, as every time I rebuild it certain hostnames and settings are unchanged, and my instance returns fairly quickly with all the necessary parameters for certs and HTTPS. I just can't seem to make any further changes to my gitlab container via the config files.

Here's how I build the container, maybe this is part of the issue? Am I missing something simple?

```
sudo docker run --detach \
   --hostname gitlab.mydomain.com \
   --publish 10443:443 --publish 10080:80 --publish 10022:22 --publish 10587:587 --publish 10025:25 \
   --name gitlab \
   --restart always \
   --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
   --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
   --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
   gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

#### UPDATE 1

If I run `gitlab-ctl diff-config` in the container, it seems to tell me that there is indeed another gitlab.rb that it is pulling from, and that it is not pulling from mine in the `/etc/gitlab/` directory within the container. It even shows me the values from my config compared to the incorrect values I see in the "package available config."

#### UPDATE 2

Went down the path thinking this may be a permissions issue. I'm not sure exactly what the suggested ownership should be for any persistent volumes that live on the host system. Mine end up owned by `root:root` every time I restart the container. Even if I make the folders owned by `root:docker`, then reconfigure/reset, it reverts back to being `root:root`. No idea if permissions is the issue, but just posting the update for information purposes in case it helps me track down the issue.

#### UPDATE 3

Ok, found a really roundabout way to bandaid my issue. Again, I think this is just a bandaid and that my `gitlab.rb` should be handling this re-config for me, I'll have to track that down when I have the time.

The gist of the bandaid: I edited each .yml and .rb file individually on the container file system that I needed to edit (just 2 for now), and have made my server rebuild script as follows. I had to do the `gitlab-ctl restart` command, as restarting the whole container overwrites these two files again.

```
sudo docker run --detach \
    --hostname gitlab.mydomain.com \
    --publish 10443:443 --publish 10080:80 --publish 10022:22 --publish 10587:587 \
    --name gitlab \
    --restart always \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
sudo docker exec gitlab cp /etc/gitlab/gitlab.yml /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml
sudo docker exec gitlab cp /etc/gitlab/smtp_settings.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb
sudo docker exec gitlab gitlab-ctl restart
```

#### UPDATE 4 (tldr;)

I had my config files and all parameters commented out... removed the single `#` from what I needed and now all is well.

Comment: This is also posted to the GitLab community forums:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/changes-made-in-gitlab-rb-are-not-set-on-reconfigure-restart-of-the-docker-container/9081

Comment: Are all your settings in `gitlab.rb` actually commented out? All lines start with `#`, which would mean they are ignored.

Comment: This is where I say, "HOLY S@#$!" I'm not super familiar with Ruby, and I assumed the single `#` was needed based on the way everything else was commented (i.e.: `###` or `##!`). I never thought to simply try that... and that is indeed the answer. Thanks for pointing out my obvious mistake, lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jdno pointed out, I had my config file parameters commented out.